# How to set locale in Blackberry Java(change date to Spanish language)

Tags: java, blackberry

How to set Spanish locale in blackberry below is my code and its giving error,

**I am using net.rim.device.api.i18n.Locale library**

```
import net.rim.device.api.i18n.Locale;
import net.rim.device.api.i18n.SimpleDateFormat;

 public static String formatDate(Date date)
    {
        String dateFormat = UserSettingManager.getUserSetting(UserSettingManager.PREF_DATE_FORMAT);
        if(StringUtils.isEmptyOrWhitespace(dateFormat))
        {
            dateFormat = DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT;
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter;
        try
        {
            if(!isLanguageChangeToSpanish()){
                    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
                }else {
                    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.get(Locale.LOCALE_es, "es"));
            }
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //If format received from server is wrong just display the default...
            if(!isLanguageChangeToSpanish()){
                    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT);
                }else {
                    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.get(Locale.LOCALE_es, "es"));
            }
            }
            return formatter.format(date);
    }
```

**ERROR** : *cannot find symbol constructor SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,net.rim.device.api.i18n.Locale)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a compiler problem.

[That constructor](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20net.rim.device.api.i18n.Locale)) exists since OS 4.5. Maybe you have the compiler set up to an older OS version?